# Restart css transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to restart a `transition` in `Javascript and without librairies or css`. I don't want to achieve this with a trick like `Settimeout` or `clientHeight`. I know it's because of reflow but I'm trying to find the ideal solution for this.

Here are the steps :

1) `Remove` transition -> set the new position (`without` transition)

2) `Add` transition -> set the new position (`with` animation)

Here is the Javascript.

```
let element1 = document.querySelector(".box")

document.querySelector("button").onclick = () => {

  element1.style.transition = "none"
  element1.style.transform = "translateY(50px)"

  element1.style.transition = "all 0.4s";
  element1.style.transform = "translateY(10px)"

}
```

Right now is only making the transition and moving by 10px instead of setting the 50px position first.

Comment: is it essential that you use transitions? is using keyframes out of the question?

Comment: Yes it's only using transition and without css or css animations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the browser don't recalculates the styles between your first and second "batch" of updates.

One trick is to force the browser recalculate them by calling one of the functions that do it. I'll use `getBoundingClientRect`, for example, as the browser needs to calculate styles to get the size and position of the element.

So:

```
let element1 = document.querySelector(".box")
document.querySelector("button").onclick = () => {
  // Call the first batch of updates
  element1.style.transition = "none";
  element1.style.transform = "translateY(50px)";
  
  // Force the browser recalculate the styles
  element1.getBoundingClientRect();

  // Call the second batch of updates
  element1.style.transition = "all 0.4s";
  element1.style.transform = "translateY(10px)";
}
```

Comment: If you call this a bunch of times per second, yes, as recalculation is not cheap (Also depends on the amount of HTML nodes, CSS complexity, layers and other bunch of factors, btw). What you want to achieve (to recalculate between batches) is not a cheap thing. By the way, I don't think that an user is going to click the button 100 times per second xD

Comment: I mean, if you don't force recalculation because you don't call any of the recalculation methods, the browser is only going to recalculate it one time per batch of updates, but if you force it, the browser is going to recalculate one time per batch of updates AND each time you force it. There are better ways to achieve this, but they require CSS or `requestAnimationFrame` (being some sort of `setTimeout`), so AFAIK, the best you can do in this scenario is what I answered.

Comment: Do you have any example with requestAnimationFrame for this case?

Comment: Is not that easy. For that is better to use a library, like `fastDOM`. `requestAnimationFrame` simply ensures that each recalculation is done 1 time per frame, not minding the amount of changes you do. Simple batches all your "reads" in one function and all your "writes" in another, and calls them one time per frame. If you do 100 reads and 50 writes in different parts of your code, they all will be "packed" into one function. In this case is exactly the same as adding a `setTimeout` as you only have one "batch" of changes. That's why I said is some sort of setTimeout. Let me prepare a fiddle.

Comment: The second one acts almost the same as adding a setTimeout, only that it will be fired just in the "paint" moment of the browser. Is more optimized for that. The second one has less performance overhead as it will be called one time per frame only, so only one recalculation will occur if the user enables an autoclicker and clicks it a thousand times per millisecond. The first way (without `requestAnimationFrame `) will be recalculated on each click, no matter the FPS.

Comment: Without CSS, yes. But if you are not able to use `setTimeout` (I don't know why), maybe you will not be allowed to use `requestAnimationFrame`. By the way you have both answers here xD

Answer (score 0):

You can add an EventListener to the transitionEnd event and then change the class:

```
let element1 = document.querySelector(".box");

element1.addEventlistener("transitionend", loopTransition(),false);
element1.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", loopTransition, false);
element1.addEventListener("mozTransitionEnd", loopTransition, false);
element1.addEventListener("msTransitionEnd", loopTransition, false);
element1.addEventListener("oTransitionEnd", loopTransition, false);


function loopTransition(e) {
  if (e.propertyName == "transform") {
      if (element1.className == "stateTwo") {
          element1.className = "stateOne";
      } else {
          element1.className = "stateTwo";
     }
  }
}
```

if you don't want to use the class you could still use this structure to change your styling.

and in you're first onclick you start the transition